# Angular 6 map it does not work

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular6

I want to make a map and from the data array that returns back-end create a new array of objects, but I always return an object. right now I'm not committed to the value but I should return a matrix of empty objects

```
//brand.ts
export class Brand {
 id : number;
 name : string;
 description : string;
 picture : string;
 provider : string;

 constructor() {
 }
}

// brand.service
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment.stage';
import { Brand } from '../../models/brand';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BrandService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getBrands() {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}brands`).pipe(
      map((a) => new Brand)
    );
  }
}

// method of component 
this.brandService.getBrands().subscribe((brands) => {
      console.log(brands);
    });

//data of back-end
[{id: 1, name: 'ssds', description: 'dsds', provider:'sds'}]
```

Comment: (1) your constructor function is empty - how would you expect javascript to populate the properties ? (2) you don't need that class Brand at all (3) just `map (a => a.map(v => v.name))` if you need to change output (notice two map operators, one is rxjs, another is array map).

Comment: Extending on @c69 's comment, if you want to use the class, you'll need to invoke the class.. `map(a => new Brand())`

Comment: gracias @c69 . ha funcionado